# Is accessing state in an action a violation of Flux principles?

Tags: reactjs, flux

I am new to React and am writing an infinite scroll functionality.

```js
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', DutyActions.scrollDuties );
```

On each scroll event, I call the action `scrollDuties`, which fetches data from the server. Then a server action called `loadDuties` is called to pass the response to the store, which it broadcasts to the views.

The issue is that on a fast scroll it makes multiple hits to API because the second scroll event fires before the `setState({loading: true})` statement renders on the page. I think the only solution is to read the state in the action and make the ajax hit only if a `loading` flag is false.

Would this violate Flux principles?

Comment: I edited this for clarity, but you'll want to add the code that has the race conditions so we can help you out a little better. Ideally, you should provide a minimum reproducible scenario.

Comment: I wouldn´t read the state from within the Action itself but from within a component instead.

Comment: Did you try to use debounce function? https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

To me it seems it should solve your problem with multiple event hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Redux flavor of Flux handles this situation in the action elegantly by way of the redux-thunk middleware.](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) In that paradigm the action creator can return a function which has a parameter to get the store. Its dispatcher knows how to evaluate this function so that the store can be exposed to the action, without creating an explicit store dependency in the action.

With more standard Flux implementations, to achieve the same decoupling, I believe you would have to pass a store parameter to the action from the component. Maybe something along the lines of:

```
doScrollAction: function (scrollParam) {
  var isLoadingStore = IsLoadingStore.getAll()
  DutyActions.scrollDuties(scrollParam, IsLoadingStore)
}

window.addEventListener( 'scroll', doScrollAction );
```